# Does Zunimasa 6 set bonus affect sacrifice?

Tags: diablo-iii

It says that we have 1500% damage. Pet does 1500 % damage.

Does that work with sacrifice? Will sacrifice, that does 1000% damage do 1500% damage on top of that? So sacrifice would do 10x15x = 150 x your damage.

Answer (score 2):

No, Zunimassa's bonus doesn't increase the damage of Sacrifice, as it's not your Pet's damage used in the calculations, it's your character's.

Comment: source? Let me check.

Comment: so zunimasa should be used with carnevil rather than sacrifice?

Comment: Source would be the skill's description:

"Banish one of your active Zombie Dogs causing it to explode, dealing 1090% of your weapon damage as Physical to all enemies..."

Keyword here being "your weapon damage

Comment: Yes. Your weapon damage. Every skill, including zombie dog bites, zombie dog punch and zombie dog fetch uses your weapon damage as base damage. So it means nothing.

Comment: Actually it means a lot, because while the skill text of the zombie dogs says "your weapon damage", that only implies his damage is derived from your weapon. After calculating, that damage is considered the pet's damage, and items that specify that will increase it (such as Mask of Jeram and Zunimassa 6p). Meanwhile, sacrifice's text clearly specifies again "your weapon damage", so it will take that into consideration, not your pet's damage.

Comment: zombie bites, zunimasa affected. zombie dogs blow up. it's not zunimasa affected?